# How to gather then mutate a new column then spread to wide format again

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Using tidyr/dplyr, I have some factor columns which I'd like to Z-score, and then mutate an average Z-score, whilst retaining the original data for reference.

I'd like to avoid using a for loop in tidyr/dplyr, thus I'm gathering my data and performing my calculation (Z-score) on a single column. However, I'm struggling with restoring the wide format.

Here is a MWE:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Original Data
dfData <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Steve","Jwan","Ashley"),
  A = c(10,20,12),
  B = c(0.2,0.3,0.5)
) %>% tbl_df() 

# Gather to Z-score
dfLong <- dfData %>% gather("Factor","Value",A:B) %>% 
  mutate(FactorZ = paste0("Z_",Factor)) %>% 
  group_by(Factor) %>% 
  mutate(ValueZ = (Value - mean(Value,na.rm = TRUE))/sd(Value,na.rm = TRUE))

# Now go wide to do some mutations (eg Z)Avg = (Z_A + Z_B)/2)

# This does not work
dfWide <- dfLong %>% 
  spread(Factor,Value) %>%
  spread(FactorZ,ValueZ)%>% 
  mutate(Z_Avg = (Z_A+Z_B)/2)


# This is the desired result
dfDesired <- dfData %>% mutate(Z_A = (A - mean(A,na.rm = TRUE))/sd(A,na.rm = TRUE)) %>% mutate(Z_B = (B - mean(B,na.rm = TRUE))/sd(B,na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
                    mutate(Z_Avg = (Z_A+Z_B)/2)
```

Thanks for any help/input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach using `dplyr` (version 0.5.0)

```
library(dplyr)

dfData  %>% 
   mutate_each(funs(Z = scale(.)), -Name) %>% 
   mutate(Z_Avg = (A_Z+B_Z)/2)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
means <-function(x)mean(x, na.rm=T)
dfWide %>% group_by(Name) %>% summarise_each(funs(means)) %>% mutate(Z_Avg = (Z_A + Z_B)/2)

# A tibble: 3 x 6
    Name     A     B        Z_A        Z_B      Z_Avg
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 Ashley    12   0.5 -0.3779645  1.0910895  0.3565625
2   Jwan    20   0.3  1.1338934 -0.2182179  0.4578378
3  Steve    10   0.2 -0.7559289 -0.8728716 -0.8144003
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach with long and wide format. For z-transformation, you can use the base function `scale`. Furthermore, this approach includes a join to combine the original data frame and the one including the new values.

```
dfLong <- dfData %>%
  gather(Factor, Value, A:B) %>%
  group_by(Factor) %>%
  mutate(ValueZ = scale(Value))

#     Name Factor Value     ValueZ
#   <fctr>  <chr> <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1  Steve      A  10.0 -0.7559289
# 2   Jwan      A  20.0  1.1338934
# 3 Ashley      A  12.0 -0.3779645
# 4  Steve      B   0.2 -0.8728716
# 5   Jwan      B   0.3 -0.2182179
# 6 Ashley      B   0.5  1.0910895   


dfWide <- dfData %>% inner_join(dfLong %>% 
                                  ungroup %>%
                                  select(-Value) %>%
                                  mutate(Factor = paste0("Z_", Factor)) %>%
                                  spread(Factor, ValueZ) %>%
                                  mutate(Z_Avg = (Z_A + Z_B) / 2))

#     Name     A     B        Z_A        Z_B      Z_Avg
#   <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1  Steve    10   0.2 -0.7559289 -0.8728716 -0.8144003
# 2   Jwan    20   0.3  1.1338934 -0.2182179  0.4578378
# 3 Ashley    12   0.5 -0.3779645  1.0910895  0.3565625
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just do it all in wide format. No need to keep switching between the long and wide formats.

```
dfData %>% 
 mutate(Z_A=(A-mean(unlist(dfData$A)))/sd(unlist(dfData$A)),
        Z_B=(B-mean(unlist(dfData$B)))/sd(unlist(dfData$B))) %>% 
 mutate(Z_AVG=(Z_A+Z_B)/2)
```

Comment: Thanks @biomiha, appreciate the input. The reason I want to switch back to wide, is that I calculate various composites of Z_A and Z_B, where Z_Avg is one.Another might be Z_1 = 0.9*Z_A, and Z_2 = 0.85*Z_A + 0.15*Z_B. I appreciate your answer - I'm learning a lot from it, thanks. How would you approach these two composites?

Comment: @csrvermaak I noticed my code didn't really give you what you wanted. Have since revised. My understanding of tidyr is that it's meant to prep your data set for manipulation rather than switching back and forth between long and wide formats.