# From long to wide format, where new generated columns flexibly reflect order of value occurrence

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I'm trying to reformat my dataset from long to wide format, but while this is one of the most discussed topics, I couldn't find a solution for my case, nor to generalize from methods others have used.

My data is in long format, where each ID has a different number of rows (relative to other IDs.) I want to transform to wide format where each ID has one row, and the data is represented by columns with a suffix that reflects the order each value appears per ID.

To illustrate:
[image: long to wide]

Notice that the NAs values don't necessarily correspond between the two formats. In the long format, NAs are simply missing from data; but in the wide format, NAs appear where values for **that id** fall short in filling the number of values other IDs might have for the variable x.

### My Data

In real life, my data has more than one variable, and it could come in one of two versions:

**Version 1 :: For each ID, values appear at the same row across variables**

```r
## reproducible data
set.seed(125)
runs_per_id <- sample(5:9, 4, replace = TRUE)
id <- rep(1:4, times = runs_per_id)

set.seed(300)
is_value <- sample (c(0, 1), size = length(id), replace = TRUE)
x <- is_value
x[which(as.logical(is_value))] <- sample(1:100, size = sum(x))
y <- is_value
y[which(as.logical(is_value))] <- sample(1:100, size = sum(y))
z <- is_value
z[which(as.logical(is_value))] <- sample(1:100, size = sum(z))
d <- as.data.frame(cbind(id, x, y, z))
d[d == 0] <- NA

d

#    id  x  y  z
# 1   1 38 63 61
# 2   1 17 27 76
# 3   1 32 81 89
# 4   1 NA NA NA
# 5   1 75  2 53
# 6   1 NA NA NA
# 7   2 NA NA NA
# 8   2 40 75  4
# 9   2 NA NA NA
# 10  2 NA NA NA
# 11  2 28 47 70
# 12  2 NA NA NA
# 13  2 71 67 33
# 14  3 NA NA NA
# 15  3 95 26 82
# 16  3 NA NA NA
# 17  3 41  7 99
# 18  3 97  8 68
# 19  4 NA NA NA
# 20  4 NA NA NA
# 21  4 93 38 58
# 22  4 NA NA NA
# 23  4 NA NA NA
```

**Version 2 :: For each ID, values don't necessarily appear at the same row across variables**

```r
## reproducible data based on generating d from above
set.seed(12)
d2 <- data.frame(replicate(3, sample(0:1,length(id),rep=TRUE)))
d2[d2 != 0] <- sample(1:100, size = sum(d2 != 0))
d2[d2 == 0] <- NA
colnames(d2) <- c("x", "y", "z")
d2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(id, d2))

d2

##    id  x  y  z
## 1   1 18 28  5
## 2   1 85 93 22
## 3   1 55 59 NA
## 4   1 NA NA 67
## 5   1 NA 15 77
## 6   1 58 NA NA
## 7   2 NA  7 NA
## 8   2 NA NA 91
## 9   2 88 14 NA
## 10  2 13 NA NA
## 11  2 32 NA NA
## 12  2 NA 80 71
## 13  2 40 74 69
## 14  3 NA NA NA
## 15  3 96 NA 76
## 16  3 NA NA NA
## 17  3 73 66 NA
## 18  3 52 NA NA
## 19  4 56 12 16
## 20  4 53 NA NA
## 21  4 NA 42 84
## 22  4 39 99 NA
## 23  4 NA 37 NA
```

### The Output I'm looking for

**Version 1's data**
[image]

**Version 2's data**
[image]

### Trying to figure this out

I've used `dplyr::spread()` and even the new experimental `pivot_wider()` (inspired by [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57020241/6105259)), but couldn't get it to *number* the occurrences of values along the variable, to be represented in the column names.

Ideally, a single solution would address both data versions I presented. It basically just needs to be agnostic to the number of values each `id` has in each column, and let the data dictate... I think it's a simple problem, but I just can't wrap my head around this.

Thanks!!!

Comment: `tidyr::gather`, filter rows with x, y, and z NAs, mutate then spread. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38260716/how-to-gather-then-mutate-a-new-column-then-spread-to-wide-format-again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a solution based on @A.Suliman comment.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

d %>% 
  # Combine all values besides id in one column
  gather(key, value, -id) %>% 
  # Filter rows without a value
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>% 
  group_by(id, key) %>% 
  # Create a new key variable numbering the key for each id
  mutate(key_new = paste0(key, seq_len(n()))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-key) %>% 
  # Spread the data with the new key
  spread(key_new, value)

# A tibble: 4 x 13
#      id    x1    x2    x3    x4    y1    y2    y3    y4    z1    z2    z3    z4
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1    38    17    32    75    63    27    81     2    61    76    89    53
# 2     2    40    28    71    NA    75    47    67    NA     4    70    33    NA
# 3     3    95    41    97    NA    26     7     8    NA    82    99    68    NA
# 4     4    93    NA    NA    NA    38    NA    NA    NA    58    NA    NA    NA
```

For `d2` instead of `d` it gives:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 13
#      id    x1    x2    x3    x4    y1    y2    y3    y4    z1    z2    z3    z4
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1    18    85    55    58    28    93    59    15     5    22    67    77
# 2     2    88    13    32    40     7    14    80    74    91    71    69    NA
# 3     3    96    73    52    NA    66    NA    NA    NA    76    NA    NA    NA
# 4     4    56    53    39    NA    12    42    99    37    16    84    NA    NA
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I was missing the critical part of `mutate(key_new = paste0(key, seq_len(n())))`, and instead hoped that some unseen magic would know to do the numbering automatically without specifically asking for it.